# Using chosen methods with Reflection class

Tags: php, laravel

In my class i have some final methods than i need to using them in another method by dynamic(if any method added, the master method Should not change),

I use `Reflection class` for get the methods:

```php
$shop_id = $shop_id ? $shop_id : $this->shop_id;
$shop = Shop::whereId($shop_id)->first();
$total_rating = 0;
$averageRatingCalculator = new AverageRatingCalculator($shop_id);
$reflection_class = new ReflectionClass($averageRatingCalculator);
$final_class_methods = $reflection_class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_FINAL);
foreach($final_class_methods as $method){
    $method_name = $method->name;
    $total_rating += $this->$method_name();
}
```

this code works well and has no problems.

Question: i want to use `Reflection` instead `$this->`,  how i must use `Reflection::invoke()` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this, but something like

```
$total_rating += $method->invoke($this);
```

So `$method` is the reflection method object from your loop (and the result of `getMethods`) and you pass in the object which you want to invoke the method on.

(from example on manual page https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php#refsect1-reflectionmethod.invoke-examples)